# Automatic deployment concept for remote iot devices

Tags: deployment, concepts, iot

I am working on a relatively large project that could include +1000 iot devices, in this case probably a Raspberry Pi. So far I only experimented with ~ 20 - 30 devices but the concept should be the same.

Currently thinking a lot about automatic **Software Updates / Deployments** on the device, when it's in the field (don't have access to it, but has internet connection).

**I have the following concept in mind :**

- Device connects to a server via websocket, along with a unique id (mac address).
- Eventually on the websocket server I see all connected devices, and I could group them under "tags" like "production" or "staging" or something similiar. (Backed by a database)
- By default / pre-installed there is this one software piece on the device which checks via the websocket server what other "modules" (scripts) should be running on the device. (Check once per startup or on-demand via websocket command).
- So the device eventually gets a signal via websocket that a new deployment is available. A deployment in this case practically includes a repository url (like on github) and "post install command" , like what the device should do after the deployment was installed ( like run "npm install" ) .
- So the devices makes sure it clones the repository and prepares it, ready to run. (Thinking about using [`simple-git`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git) here).
- Once the deployment is available on the device, it can be started/stopped, again automatically or on-demand via websocket command (Thinking about using [`pm2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) here).

The "modules" (which the device would download and run) most-likely would be other NodeJS scripts, simple bash scripts or just terminal commands (for a one-time-run).

**What if a already installed module updates ?**
I tried to rule that out as I thought it overcomplicates things again. If the server says there is a new deployment, the devices basically downloads it again (it doesn't has to know it's already there) and then removes all other un-needed modules. This also gives me kind-of a safety net if a faulty version of the module gets pushed. Just create a new deployment with the fixed version.

**What if the base software (handles deployment installs) on the device needs an update ?** It shouldn't need an update. Currently with this concept it wouldn't be possible.

### Question

My question here would be : Am I competely out of my mind and crazy only thinking about considering this for a production environment or ... Am I on a not-so-bad-looking track here ? I always have this keyword ("docker") floating around my head but I thought it would be too OP for this case and would over-complicate things. Also, bulletproof error handliny aside, can you think about something the might lead to trouble going down this path ?

Comment: This sound similar to what Balena does: https://www.balena.io/what-is-balena

Comment: I stumbled over balena some time ago, but their hosted service is too expansive to start with. They have an open-source variant to self-host but it's hard to scale in the current state. It also requires a specific OS. I tried it, it's cool ... but might be too complicated .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By reinventing the wheel, you are making things more complicated than needed.

A Rhaspberry Pi comes with a very capable package manager (apt) that can also do automatic (unattended) updates.

What you would need to do is create a repository for Debian packages (essentially a set of HTTP-accessible files and folders with a particular structure) and host your releases there.

Then, the only hurdle left is to configure `apt` to use your package repository, to write a small script that periodically asks `apt` to check for updates and install them and to have your packages installed initially on each device. Those are all actions that need to be done once when commissioning a new device.

Comment: Thanks for giving this another angle. While I get that my approach could seen as "reinventing" the wheel  - I don't fully see how your approach would be "less" reinventing  . Would this just swap `git` with `apt` ? ... Also when you say "configure `apt` to use your p rep" - does this mean it will use my repository only and I can't install other third-party deb packages anymore ?

Comment: That said  I'll definitely checkout `apt` to see if it fits my need so thanks for bringing it to the table !

Comment: Git won't handle base system package dependencies, where apt will.  (I've used git for trivial software distribution, however, so it's not a terrible idea.)  Also, you could make a metapackage in your repo that pulls in other packages both in your repo and in the base system, and could handle deprecating old packages as well.

Comment: `apt` would take care of the whole sequence of compare installed version to repository -> download new version -> install new version -> run post-install script. And it can be configured to check multiple repositories, so you can also still use third-party packages. Which is good, because it also automatically handles dependencies.

Comment: So `apt` would be a better fit because it also handles base system package dependencies. What about the rest of menu : handling / controlling it via websocket - would that be an appropiate choice ? How about doing the process management (running/stopping) ... i am not sure if `pm2` is a good fit for it then ... 

Comment: The process management is typically handled by scripts that are part of the packages being installed/updated through `apt` to give you the smallest amount of down time. I would not consider websockets to be appropriate for software update triggers in any case, unless you are piggybacking on an existing connection.

Answer (score 1):

I allow myself to disagree with *Bart van Ingen Schenau*. I don't think you are reinventing the wheel.

Have you considered [Ultibo](https://ultibo.org/)?

It is a completely different approach into programming Raspberry Pis, in which you're writing (in Pascal / Delphi) **your own kernel** -- your very own system + application layer (bye, bye Linux). Depending on what your IoT device will be doing your entire image can be as little as 1 MB. And have it all.

Start reading [here](https://ultibo.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4639#p4639) and never come back to the real world. This is the place, where I felt in love with Ultibo with a passionate love so deep that I have completely removed all this Linux, Python, apt etc. stuff from my mind.

You can also find more details here: [Developing for Raspberry Pi with Ultibo](https://onezeronull.com/2021/05/21/developing-for-raspberry-pi-with-ultibo/).

As for your question, an automatic kernel / code update, [Ultibo has a lot of options for you](https://onezeronull.com/2021/08/10/quality-assurance-in-ultibo/#updating-kernel-image). Internet (HTTP, FTP, SSH, Telnet), direct serial cable connection to name at start.

Now, the question is, if you project allows to consider developing with your own kernel and forgetting about all the Linux-related stuff. Such approach has as many pros as cons.